# Merge replication Problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, merge-replication

I have got some problem to implement Merge Replication in SQL server 2008 R2 which send me the error response at the time of Synchronization using PULL from Publisher. I have tried to solve the problem by Stopping Merge Agent from JOB in sql server, Restart SQL Server Agent services, from Sql Server Agent JOB history i have again tried to restart specific Merge JOB agent but i have got still same problem which Show in below error :
[image]

After that when i forcefully tried to start above synchronization process then another error message shown which is below :
[image]

Can you please help me to resolve this issue in SQL server.
​

Comment: What is displayed in the (Replication) Monitor? Did you stop all replication jobs? If I recall correctly there are up to three jobs for a replication. You might have to have a look at the distribution server and/or publisher server and/or subscription server to localise the issues.